# Spatial receive diversity and antenna coupling

Tags: wireless

Spatial Receive Diversity works best if the receive antennas are not correlated, i.e. if each antenna sees a different wireless channel.

MRC ensures that in case of 2 antennas for example , the 2 signals will be weighted and combined in phase (the data stream is the same in case of diversity)

What happens if there is mutual coupling between the antennas which results in an isolation that does not exceed the SNR required to detect the signal.

The signals at each antenna are not aligned (not yet) so they would contaminate each other, how is this dealt with in practice?

Comment: The two antennas use different receive circuits hence what's the problem? What does MRC mean?

Comment: MRC stands for Maximal Ratio Combining, which ensures that the two signals will be added in phase and ensures the best possible SNR, now if they contaminate each other before combining in phase takes place, then there is the problem I am asking about